# An ajax request fails and I cannot figure out why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

for some very weird reason my ajax request keeps returning as an error, however the data does get added to the database. In the console it just shows a whole bunch of stuff in terms of when I log the error and I can't understand where exactly it is coming from. All the php/html/naming is correct as this used to work, however I don't understand why this happens.

Code:

```
function doShorten(event)
 {
event.preventDefault();

var form_data = {
    long_url : $("[name='long_url']").val()
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url/short_ajax",
    data: form_data,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 10000,

    beforeSend: function() {
        console.log("About to send");
    },

    complete: function() {
        console.log("Complete", this.url);
    },

    success: function(data){
        console.log("Success", this.url);
        $('#shorty').addClass('shorty').html("Short URL: "+data);
    },

    error: function(error) {
        console.log("Error", this.url, error);
    }

});
}
```

Please help!

```
Stuff I get in the console:
    abort: function (a){a=a||"abort",p&&p.abort(a),w(0,a);return this}
always: function (){i.done.apply(i,arguments).fail.apply(i,arguments);return this}
complete: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
done: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
error: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
fail: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return s===2?n:null}
getResponseHeader: function (a){var c;if(s===2){if(!o){o={};while(c=bG.exec(n))o[c[1].toLowerCase()]=c[2]}c=o[a.toLowerCase()]}return c===b?null:c}
isRejected: function (){return!!i}
isResolved: function (){return!!i}
overrideMimeType: function (a){s||(d.mimeType=a);return this}
pipe: function (a,b,c){return f.Deferred(function(d){f.each({done:[a,"resolve"],fail:[b,"reject"],progress:[c,"notify"]},function(a,b){var c=b[0],e=b[1],g;f.isFunction(c)?i[a](function(){g=c.apply(this,arguments),g&&f.isFunction(g.promise)?g.promise().then(d.resolve,d.reject,d.notify):d[e+"With"](this===i?d:this,[g])}):i[a](d[e])})}).promise()}
progress: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
promise: function (a){if(a==null)a=h;else for(var b in h)a[b]=h[b];return a}
readyState: 4
responseText: "http://localhost/u/pRam"
setRequestHeader: function (a,b){if(!s){var c=a.toLowerCase();a=m[c]=m[c]||a,l[a]=b}return this}
state: function (){return e}
status: 200
statusCode: function (a){if(a){var b;if(s<2)for(b in a)j[b]=[j[b],a[b]];else    b=a[v.status],v.then(b,b)}return this}
statusText: "OK"
success: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
then: function (a,b,c){i.done(a).fail(b).progress(c);return this}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: "A bunch of stuff in the error log" Really? -1.

Comment: Is the function only called after the DOM has loaded? Also, have you examined the request and response using AJAX tools in the browser? @asawyer is correct in that we really need to see a snippet of the logs to give you a sensible answer, and it is the lack of detail that explains why you're currently being downvoted.

Comment: Im sorry about that, I am new to jQuery, but it returns a whole bunch of stuff, im not sure what part you would want to see. But here goes:

Answer (score 4):

make sure the **url** is correct, maybe you meant :

```
url: "url/short_ajax.php",
```

Comment: This is the exact stuff from the console:

Comment: that's because you did `console.log(this)`